# Silverlight - Make same size as browser frame

Tags: silverlight

Is there a way to scale a silverlight app to 100% width and 100% height of the browser frame that the application is embedded in?

I'm aware of the full screen capabilities, I'd like it to sit nicely inside the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Width=”Auto” Height=”Auto”` on your LayoutRoot will cause Silverlight object to fill the room the object tag has. By default (TestPage.html) it is object ... width="100%" height="100%" You might also want to set the d:DesignWidth="640" and d:DesignHeight="480" that way it is easier to do layout in Expression Blend.

Comment: Thank you, the Auto keyword was indeed the one I needed. So simple, yet so easy to miss!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the Width and Height attributes from the root UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

This Javascript will do it, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726964/filling-browser-window-with-silverlight-application/2874443#2874443):

```
private bool _hasResized;

protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
{
    if (!_hasResized)
    {
        HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("silverlightControlHost").SetStyleAttribute("height", finalSize.Height.ToString());
        _hasResized = true;
    }

    return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
}
```