# Filling Browser Window with Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, browser, size

I want my Silverlight app to fill the entire browser window. I've set the plugin object width and height to 100%, and set my LayoutRoot container's height and width to Auto, but still no luck. Any suggestions?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Silverlight ID="Silverlight1" runat="server" 
        Source="~/ClientBin/Client.xap"
        MinimumVersion="2.0.30818.0"
        AutoUpgrade="true"
        Height="100%" 
        Width="100%">
    </asp:Silverlight>
</form>

<UserControl 
    x:Class="Client.Page"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Height="Auto"
    Width="Auto">
    <Grid 
        x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
        Background="#084E85"
        ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="280" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="600" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        ...Remaining content here...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Disclaimer:** I searched for an answer first, finding [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441143/silverlight-make-same-size-as-browser-frame). However, as you can see by my code that isn't working for me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, I don't set the height/width in the user control.  Instead, I set the DesignHeight and DesignWidth (in the "`http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008`" namespace) and I set the alignment to stretch

```
<UserControl ... 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    d:DesignHeight="1050" d:DesignWidth="1680">
```

In my HTML, I set the Height and Width to 100% like this...

```
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: fixed;">
        <asp:Silverlight runat="server" Source="~/ClientBin/My.xap" ID="MyId" 
            Width="100%" Height="100%" />
</div>
```

At that point, everything works for me to have it take the entire window.

Comment: One thing I'd add (which I found out the hard way): if you're hosting controls within other controls, and you want the hosted control to fill the entire screen, you should use a Grid rather than a Canvas as the LayoutRoot for the hosting control.  A Canvas only supports absolute layout, and consequently ignores any HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" or VerticalAlignment="Stretch" attributes.  So if you use a Canvas for your hosting control, the hosted control will always be sized to the minimum size required to support all the elements it contains.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if you have your <div> inside another div, or a complex design, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: +1 Just searched for this issue and this solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Height and Width attributes from the :

```
<UserControl
     x:Class="Client.Page"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
```

Auto Height and Width with resize the window to fit the content. If you remove the Height and Width attributes, your Silverlight Application will grow to fit the window.

Comment: If you remove the height and width completely, it doesn't render properly in the designer... see DesignHeight and DesignWidth

Answer (score 0):

Hmm

I'm thinking your Grid is set-up to be as small as possible (no "star" column or row).
Can you try with one more column and row with a "star" size ?

as other have pointed out, you also need to remove the "auto" sizes, since they auto-size to content.

also try to set a background color on the page, so you see where it actually extends.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a fairly complex HTML layout and can't rely on fixed positioning then you can make the #silverlightControlHost div resize using the following:

```
private bool _hasResized;

protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
{
    if (!_hasResized)
    {
        HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("silverlightControlHost").SetStyleAttribute("height", finalSize.Height.ToString());
        _hasResized = true;
    }

    return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
}
```

You can put this inside `MainPage.cs` or if you have nested `UserControls`, then the control that requires the most height. I'm also using the following XAML and the default HTML Visual Studio provides

```
<UserControl ...
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Height="Auto"
    Width="Auto">
```

I haven't tested it without these settings, as far as I know Auto is the default.