# Using Browser ScrollBars for Silverlight4 App

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, resize

I'm trying to make my Silverlight app behave like any other web app for layout.

I have followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726964/filling-browser-window-with-silverlight-application/2874443#2874443) that shows how to expand the app to fill the available space when the app takes up less area than the client window.

However, I cannot seem to find code that does the opposite.  That is, when my app becomes larger than the client area of the browser, I would like the browser to display the appropriate scroll bars.  Currently, the code above simply clips the application at the size of the browser.

Here is an simple example app:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightWidthAndHeight.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>        

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0"
                   Fill="Blue" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" 
                   Foreground="White"
                   FontSize="20"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Margin="5"
                   Text="Header" />

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1"
                   Fill="Red" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtMiddleRow" 
                           Foreground="White"
                           FontSize="28"
                           Text="Middle Row" />

            <Button x:Name="btnGrow"
                        Content="Grow"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="5" />
        </StackPanel>


        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2"
                   Fill="Blue" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" 
                   Foreground="White"
                   FontSize="20"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Margin="5"
                   Text="Footer" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

As you can see, it fills the space appropriately:
[image: Silverlight App Extended]

But if I press the "Grow" button to increase the font size of the TextBlock:
[image: Silverlight App Clipped]

I understand that I can wrap everything in a ScrollViewer, but it looks like such a hack to have a scrollbar immediately to the left of the browser scrollbar.

Thanks,
wTs

Comment: What about just hiding the browser scrollbar?  Then you can just use SL scrollviewer, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is for silverlight to resize itself. This will take alot of work on your part. You will need to write code that knows when your app gets larger, and it will scale the html object that is holding your silverlight app.

For example, set an event on the layoutroot for layoutchange, then set the height property of your silverlight app from code. Take a look at how to manipulate html and call javascript from silverlight [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/03/09/calling-javascript-functions-from-silverlight-2.aspx).